# POST not working for Mocha/Chai tests on Express REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mocha.js, chai

I'm having a problem with Mocha tests on my Express app. I have a REST API set up that I know works in the browser, but it's getting a bit large and therefore manual testing has become tedious.

Anyway, all my **GET** tests work just fine, but when I add tests for my **POST** requests, they fail:

```
 Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (domain, _events, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 400
  at testPostSingle (test-app.js:297:21)
  at test-app.js:195:21
  at Test.Request.callback (/home/jacobd/healthboard/node_modules/chai-http/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:603:3)
  at Stream.<anonymous> (/home/jacobd/healthboard/node_modules/chai-http/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:767:18)
  at Unzip.<anonymous> (/home/jacobd/healthboard/node_modules/chai-http/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/utils.js:108:12)
  at _stream_readable.js:944:16
```

I'm using Mocha, with the Chai should library and chai-http for requests.

## My relevant code:

```
models.forEach(function(model, i) {

    var url = '/api/v1/' + model;
    var list = lists[i];

    /****************************** API POST TESTS ******************************/

    describe(util.format('API: /%s POST', model), function() {
        var minArgsObj = {
            title: 'Test ' + model + ' Title'
        };

        // Initialize list at start
        before(function(done) {
            instances._init(function(err) {
                if (!err) done();
            });
        });

        // Nuke list before each test
        beforeEach(function(done) {
            list.clear();
            done();
        });

        // Make sure POST single object works
        it('should create and add model on ' + url + ' with minimal arguments', function(done) {
            var req = {};
            req.options = _.clone(minArgsObj);
            chai.request('server')
                .post(url)
                .send(req)
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    testPostSingle(res, minArgsObj);
                    list.list.length.should.equal(1);
                    res.body.should.eql(list.list[0]);
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
});


function testPostSingle(res, ref) {
    res.should.have.status(200);
    ...
}
```

When I put a log message in the **POST** route declaration, it doesn't show up, so that tells me that my request is getting stopped before even hitting my server. Maybe the route isn't getting mounted properly in Mocha? It works when I make the request outside of Mocha, but I can't figure out why it won't work in a test environment.

Thanks in advance for your help, and let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 0):

The relevant code is in testPostSingle.  Your call is returning 400 bad request.  Are you sure the route is correct or is set up to handle POST as well as GET?  Are you sure parameters are correct?  Make testPostSingle print out the body of the HTTP response so you know the details.  You can also add some debug code in the route for that request on your server.

Comment: I know it's mounted properly, because POST requests work outside of a Mocha environment (i.e. when I run the server with `node app.js` and curl POST requests, everything works as expected).

Comment: I am certain the parameters are correct; I went so far as to log the object to the console before sending, and then copy/pasted that object to try on my dev environment, and it worked

Comment: OK. Rest of answer still applies. Make testPostSingle print out the body of the HTTP response so you know the details. You can also add some debug code in the route for that request on your server.

Comment: The response returns a generic 400.html page that is not a part of my app, but the network its running on. I tried logging from the route on my server, but none of that code is being reached in these tests. Also, the test fails in the first line of TestPostSingle

Comment: Maybe try with chai.request('http://localhost:1234') or chai.request('http://127.0.0.1:1234') or using external ip instead of chai.request(server).

Comment: Oh wow. Should be `chai.request(server)` not `chai.request('server')`

Problem solved

Comment: Oh, yeah I actually thought you wrote the variable `server`. Weird, I read that wrong.  Interesting how brains work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm terrible and issue is very simple:

Instead of `chai.request('server')`

It needs to be `chai.request(server)`

Thanks to [Jason Livesay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281920/jason-livesay) for pointing me at the right line!